# Are invertebrates and vertebrates universal?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, evolution

Im making a speculative biology project and I was wondering if vertebrates and invertebrates are universal classes of animals that if animals were to evolve on other planets, would they be able to be classified as invertebrates or vertebrates ?

Comment: In as much as they are boolean opposites (vertebrates have one or more backbone(s) and invertebrates have zero backbones), everything, living or dead, fit into one of those two categories.  Almost everything in the universe is invertebrate.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Well, technically, no because invertebrate doesn't just mean "no spine". Having a spine is a necessary and sufficient condition for being a vertebrate, while not having a spine is a necessary, but insufficient condition for being an invertebrate. There are additional conditions for being an invertebrate (it just so happens that we know of no instance where you can have a spine while not satisfying those same conditions so we don't worry about it for vertebrates). The reason being that things like plants, microrganisms, and inanimate objects are not counted among invertebrates.

Comment: *"Vertebrates and invertebrates are universal classes ":* Vertebrates are indeed a class (phylum Chordata, class Vertebrata), but "invertebrates" are a purely popular designation, with no correspondent in biological classification. *Invertebrates are not a class,* either in the popular meaning (where it means nothing more that not a vertebrate), or in taxonomical terminology (where it has no meaning). You could as well say that insects and non-insects are universal classes. Some invertebrates (such as, for example, starfish) are more closely related to vertebrates than to other invertebrates.

Comment: @AlexP Huh. yeah, you're right. Invertebrates is pretty informal.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal.  There are 11 phyla in the animal kingdom.  Chordates (vertebrates) are just one.  "Invertebrate" really does not do the other 11 justice.

Answer (score 4):

### NO

Life on earth is over 4.5 billion years old.  Vertebrates evolved about 500 million years ago.

That is, the classification didn't even apply on this planet for more than 80% of life's existence on it.  It is improbable that we could be confident that the same anatomy would appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is Worldbuilding, but...

## Simplistically, Yes

Vertebrates have spines, invertebrates do not.  [Convergent evolution](https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/convergent_evolution.htm) would suggest that if there's a biosphere where life evolves that's anything like Earth, you'd get earth-like animals eventually.

The reason spines are so common is because they're useful, structurally speaking.  Not only can you hang other bits (like ribs and whatnot) off of them, but having a protected column to store your high-bandwidth nerves in is beneficial from a survival perspective.

Now, if it's not an earth-like planet (all water, say, or a Venutian-style atmosphere with something like floating plankton), then all bets are off over whether something spinelike will evolve at all, but in that case, the classification is trivial - they're invertebrates.

(All this assumes that humans are the ones doing the classification.  If the dominant sapient form of life on this speculative planet are cephalopods, they may not place much importance in spines, and would use a different classification system.)

Comment: To clarify - vertebrates (on Earth) are a subclassification of [chordates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordate), which also can have a dorsal nerve column protected by something stiff.  Generally, the vertebral design allows for greater flexibility, and is likely to have parallels in speculative xenobiology.

Comment: The general body plan of a chordate the dorsal nerve chord is *above* the notochord. The role of the notochord is to provide an elastic antagonist to the muscles, not to protect the nerve chord (which is placed *exterior* to the notochord).

Answer (score 1):

No more than winged and no wings, or legged and no legged, shelled or unshelled. But we don't use these as biological classifications on Earth simply because they have occurred multiple times independently of a common ancestors, as well as disappearing and re-appearing or being the result of convergent evolution. Therefore these classifications are not useful for delineating evolutionary branches.

If we suddenly found evidence of a branch with vertebrae disappearing and re-appearing, or appearing independently of inheritance from a common ancestor of other vertebrates, then the classification of vertebrates vs invertebrates becomes similar to those I described at the beginning and is therefore no longer useful for delineating evolutionary branches or common ancestors.

The thing about classifications, is that classifications are rather arbitrary human constructs and you can classify things however you want. Ultimately you have to ask yourself: is the classification useful for your purpose? On a world where spines have evolved multiple times independently but all winged animals have wings because they all inherited them from a common ancestor then suddenly wing vs wingless becomes a very useful classification while vertebrates vs invertebrates becomes a useless for taxonomy.

**Example 1:** If you found two planets where vertebrates and invertebrates evolved and inherited that trait from a common ancestor unique to each planet (i.e. useful for taxonomical classification), you still would not group these vertebrates (or invertebrates) from both planets under the same group if your goal is taxonomy. It doesn't make sense. It's not useful for taxonomy since they are just results of convergent evolution.

**Example 2:** What if an animal had a central nerve bundle protected by a rigid column that ran through it's body laterally (rather than longitudinally). Does that count as a spine? Is that a vertebrate? Would it be useful to group that animal in with other vertebrates having dorsal spines for taxonomical purposes even though its completely unrelated?

(It's really freakin' unlikely that the spin would rotate 90 degrees such that dorsal and lateral "spined" animals share a common ancestor.)

**Example 3:** What if the world only ever evolved invertebrates? Spines never evolved? Would it be useful to classify everything on that world as invertebrate? If we did that on Earth it would be like dreaming up a taxonomical classification for something we have never seen (left-handed helix DNA for example) and then putting every organism under our sun in the opposite classification.

So in short if I were to answer your question literally, as worded, the answer would be yes. But if I am correctly understanding the *intent* of your question, the answer would be no.

Comment: "It's really freakin' unlikely that the spin would rotate 90 degrees": not so much: according to some scientists, vertebrates have each emishphere of the brain controlling the opposite side of the body because at some point of evolutionary history, [the main neural chord twisted by 180 degrees with respect to the brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contralateral_brain#Axial_twist_hypothesis)

Comment: @McTroopers Interesting

Comment: thanks for the answer